# Mysql table joins using a where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a MySQL query against a database and join 3 tables together.

I have 3 tables in the database;

Table containing the important data

```
+----+-------+----------------------+
| id | name  | value                |
+----+-------+----------------------+
|  1 | data1 | First piece of data  |
|  2 | data2 | Second piece of data |
|  3 | data3 | Third piece of data  |
+----+-------+----------------------+
```

Table containing flag_id to flag_name

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | name  | description |
+----+-------+-------------+
|  1 | flag1 | NULL        |
|  2 | flag2 | NULL        |
|  3 | flag3 | NULL        |
|  4 | flag4 | NULL        |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

Table containing the one-to-many data to flag mapping

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+
| id | type_id | status | data_id |
+----+---------+--------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | 0      |       1 |
|  2 |       2 | 0      |       1 |
|  3 |       4 | 1      |       1 |
|  4 |       2 | 0      |       2 |
|  5 |       3 | 0      |       2 |
|  6 |       4 | 1      |       2 |
|  7 |       3 | 0      |       3 |
|  8 |       4 | 1      |       3 |
+----+---------+--------+---------+
```

I want to be able to have a single query that will show me each named flag as a column for each piece of data.  In searching the web, I found an example doing it using this query:

```
select d.id, d.name, d.value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 1 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 2 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 3 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 4 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag4
from data d
    inner join flags f on f.data_id = d.id
group by d.id
```

Which gives the result I want.

```
+----+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | name  | value                | flag1 | flag2 | flag3 | flag4 |
+----+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | data1 | First piece of data  | 0     | 0     | NULL  | 1     |
|  2 | data2 | Second piece of data | NULL  | 0     | 0     | 1     |
|  3 | data3 | Third piece of data  | NULL  | NULL  | 0     | 1     |
+----+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The problem is that I need to add a where clause to filter on specific flags, but I get the error that 'flag4' is an Unknown column, which is because an alias cannot be used in a where clause.

How do I accomplish this, preferably in a single query that I can use with a 'where' clause?

Comment: what does `id` in the mapping table do?

Comment: Column aliases are not available in `WHERE`, but you can do `HAVING flag4 = 'your condition'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use `where`, use `having`.

The `flag` columns are the result of an aggregating operation, so, if you want to apply a selection criteria on them, you have to use having. Example:

```
select d.id, d.name, d.value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 1 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 2 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 3 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 4 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as flag4
from data d
    inner join flags f on f.data_id = d.id
group by d.id
havig flag1 = 0
```